# How to install Kdevelop on Macos using homebrew-kde from github after setting up kde

Tags: git, macos, qt, kde-plasma, kdevelop

i want to install `Kdevelop` on MacOS/OSX i followed these steps:

---

https://github.com/KDE-mac/homebrew-kde 
i don't know how to install `kdevelop` after installing KDE from

> https://github.com/KDE-mac/homebrew-kde

this repo so, i need a way to install the `kdevelop IDE` after following the steps on github repo .

Answer (score 2):

Use below link to complete the installation[link](https://github.com/adymo/homebrew-kde)

Prepare your environment:

Append these codes to your `~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile:`

```
export KDEDIRS=$KDEDIRS:$HOME/Library/Preferences/KDE:/usr/local/kde4
export PATH=/usr/local/kde4/bin:$PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/kde4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/kde4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/Library/Preferences/KDE/share
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/kde4/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
```

If you were using this tap before Feb 17, 2014, kde stuff were installed to /usr/local and you cannot uninstall them. Which means your /usr/local is already messed up. Please backup everything important, sudo rm -rf /usr/local/*, reinstall homebrew and all your formulas, and anything else you put under /usr/local.
Now kde stuff are installed to /usr/local/kde4, you still cannot uninstall single kde formula, but you can safely nuke that directory and reinstall kde formulas you want to keep.
We're working on a solution to make kde formulas install to their own kegs.

Tap my KDE repository:

```
brew tap adymo/kde
```

Compile Qt with D-Bus and Qt3 support. KDE will not work without that.

```
brew uninstall qt
brew install qt --with-d-bus --with-qt3support
```

Install KDE applications

```
brew install kate
brew install kdevelop
brew install kdevelop-ruby
brew install ...
```

Launch D-Bus

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents

# substitute Cellar/d-bus/1.8.0 below with your actual dbus installation dir
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.8.0/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist
```

Update system configuration:

relogin or restart your system

```
kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental
update-mime-database /usr/local/share/mime
update-mime-database /usr/local/kde4/share/mime
```

Create application links (so that Finder and Launchpad see KDE apps):

```
brew linkapps
```

Run KDE apps from Launchpad or from command line:

```
open /Applications/kdevelop.app
```

Troubleshooting

if kbuildsycoca4 never finishes, then stop dbus, remove its lock file (run env | grep DBUS to find out where it is) and start dbus again
if dbus fails to start, check whether you have /usr/local/etc/dbus-1/session.d directory
sometimes after App Store run upgrades, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH will be reset, then some plugins will fail to load, run launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/kde4/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in terminal to fix
if kbuildsycoca or any other KDE app hangs during start, upgrade d-bus or recompile dbus from sources (installations from bottles was broken at some point, it was missing important configuration files): brew uninstall dbus && brew install dbus --build-from-source

Comment: can you explain how to do this step i am a bit confused Append these codes to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile

Comment: You can run this command in Terminal, which will append the line to your .bash_profile:

echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile

.bash_profile just a normal plain text file - you can edit it with any text editor, including vi or nano, or even a graphical editor like TextEdit. It's up to you - just remember to save it as a plain-text file.

Comment: it's to long to paste so here is a like to pastebin containing the error
https://pastebin.com/1KsXVgCu

Comment: It is because home-brew does not see a Qt5 installation. You will need to install Qt5 using home-brew. Install it. Please google more and find the answer to such problems.

Comment: i have QT5 installed but i think it is a problem that doesn't have a fix yet https://github.com/adymo/homebrew-kde/issues/77 here are some people who are facing the same problem if you know how to fix it please help answer this issue anyway thanks for your time and help

Comment: May be this helps if there is a fix for tap: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/6513